# Django migrate Killed every time

Tags: django, migrate

I uploaded an update to my production server. Every time I run migrate (`python manage.py migrate`), which took only a few seconds on my development machine, it hangs for a long time and then simply says "Killed".

This also bounces me out of the `pipenv shell`. I have tried using the migrate flags `--list`, `--plan`, and `--fake`, but they all do the same thing, hang and then "Killed." I accidentally ran `makemigrations` on the production machine first. Is that what screwed it up? How can I find out what is killing the process? And how can I fix it?

I desperately need to update the database to run the code that got installed. I have checked the database and none of the changes have been made. Also the migration files in the app have not been corrupted either. I am at a loss here.

Frank

Comment: If you ran `makemigrations` on the server, can you redeploy (or remove all files and add everything again) to ensure there's nothing new on there that you don't have locally, then reboot & re-run migrate?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I guess you are saying that `makemigrations` might do something other than create new migration files? Frankly, I am too nervous to delete everything and start over. Is there any less drastic solution you can offer? And by "everything" do you mean just the code in the repository or do you mean the database as well? I could dump the database and reload the data, I guess, but then whatever changed in the database will still be there. So I don't see how that will help.

Comment: I am on DigitalOcean so maybe I'll just try rebooting the Droplet in the morning. The website is currently running only because I did not restart wsgi to load the change in the code into the webserver. Can I update the database by simply running the migration files without using manage.py?

Comment: You build a Greate Website .

Comment: Well you've not mentioned how you deploy, but I just meant remove the project files. Perhaps the new migrations on the server conflict with that is there already and `migrate` can't complete which is why you're seeing this happen. Like the current answer says though, you could change the verbosity flag on `migrate` to see if that tells you anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it turned out to be a memory issue. I did not realize I was running in such a tight environment on my Digital Ocean droplet. I increased the memory size using their web interface and all is fine now. Thanks for everyone who at least considered my issue and to Erwin for suggesting that it was a memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run `python manage.py migrate -v 3` to make the output more verbose and see if you can find anything from there.

And did you make sure to stop the Django process (e.g. gunicorn) before migrating? On your local machine when using `runserver` it won't matter much, but in production using for example gunicorn, the database may be locked.

Comment: Unfortunately the -v flag didn't help either:
`$ python manage.py migrate -v 3
Killed`

I'm running nginx, and no I did not stop it. I wasn't aware that I should. I can still create new records using the website though.

Comment: It may be an memory issue. On your development machine your dealing with little data (I guess), on production it presumably is much more, hence the difference between local and production.

Can you update your question with the latest migration file?

Answer (score 0):

most probably you set the DEBUG to True, it will log lots of actions and consume all resources, set it to False and you'll notice significant difference in performance.

as a side note:
try all args of command, see `makemigrations/migrate --help`